# Set default webpage language

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to set default language for website, and for this I made following changes:

```
          Settings > Website Settings > Default Language -> [mylang]
```

But after applying changes, website is still in English, only changed URL now English has en_US

[image]

I've tried to clean cache but still same result - website is in English

There is only me having this problem?